# How to handle date in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I am displaying the date to the user, on a search form, in 'dd/mm/yyyy' format, using the jquery datepicker. My target audience is British. But, when I try to use this date for a query on a model with DateField, I get this exception

```
Enter a valid date in YYYY-MM-DD format.
```

So, how should I handle this scenario?

Answer (score 4):

You have two choices.

Use a [`form.DateField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#datefield) - which will normalize to a date time object that you can use directly in your query. Just assign the jquery object to the date field:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
        $("#id_MyDateField").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });

 });
</script>
```

Convert the date manually:

```
form_date = request.GET.get('the_date',datetime.datetime.now()) # defaults to now
db_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(form_date,'%d/%m/%y')
```

Then use `db_date` in your query

Answer (score 0):

Enter a valid date in YYYY-MM-DD format.

In other words, transform the date from one format to the other.