# strptime validation error django

Tags: python, django, strptime

I have a daterangepicker from which the users set date. The choice of format is "DD MMM YYYY"
now to go with that i'm using

```
    datetime.datetime.strptime(time, "%d %b %Y");
```

but still i am getting an error

```
    Exception Value:[u"'01 Aug 2013' value has an invalid date format. It must be in   YYYY-MM-DD format."]
```

any idea what might be going wrong? stuck on this for a while.

```
    def form_valid(self, form):
      new_obj = form.save(commit=False)
      new_obj.date_pickup_from, new_obj.date_pickup_to = form.cleaned_data['pickup_daterange'].split(' to ')
      new_obj.date_delivery_from, new_obj.date_delivery_to = form.cleaned_data['delivery_daterange'].split(' to ')
```

here are the forms

```
pickup_daterange = forms.CharField(
    label=_('Pickup Within'),
    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'daterange'}),
    validators=[
        RegexValidator(
            regex=r'\d{2}\ \w{3}\ \d{4}\ to\ \d{2}\ \w{3}\ \d{4}',
            message=_(u'Range must be of format "mm/dd/yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy"'),
            code='invalid_range'
        )
    ],
    help_text=_('Within what dates do you want the pickup?')
)
delivery_daterange = forms.CharField(
    label=_('Delivery Within'),
    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'daterange'}),
    validators=[
        RegexValidator(
            regex=r'\d{2}\ \w{3}\ \d{4}\ to\ \d{2}\ \w{3}\ \d{4}',
            message=_(u'Range must be of format "mm/dd/yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy"'),
            code='invalid_range'
        )
    ],
    help_text=_('Within what dates do you want the delivery?')
)
```

models.py

```
date_delivery_from = models.DateField(_('Date of Delivery From'), blank=True, null=True)
date_delivery_to = models.DateField(_('Date of Delivery To'), blank=True, null=True)
```

function in my form class from where i am calling strptime

```
    def clean_delivery_daterange(self):
      daterange_pattern = re.compile(r'(\d{2}\ \w{3}\ \d{4})\ to\ (\d{2}\ \w{3}\ \d{4})')
      delivery_daterange = self.cleaned_data['delivery_daterange']
      pickup_daterange = self.cleaned_data['pickup_daterange']

      str_pickup_from, str_pickup_to = daterange_pattern.search(pickup_daterange).groups()
      str_delivery_from, str_delivery_to = daterange_pattern.search(delivery_daterange).groups()

      delivery_from = datetime.datetime.strptime(str_delivery_from, "%d %b %Y")
      pickup_from = datetime.datetime.strptime(str_pickup_from, "%d %b %Y")
      if delivery_from < pickup_from:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Delivery dates cannot be before pickup dates')
      return delivery_daterange
```

Comment: Are you using a Django form `DateField`?

Comment: no. I am not, should I?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159887/how-to-handle-date-in-django I went through this, and trying to convert the date manually.

Comment: It's generally simplest when you're handling user input.  But if you don't want to, I'd need to see your code showing what you're doing to `request.POST` to try to convert it and where you're assigning it.

Comment: What form fields are you using?

Comment: edited. that is what i have on my view.

Comment: CharField with TextInput widget. should i add the form?

Comment: More information is always better.  Are `date_pickup_from` and `date_pickup_to` model `DateFields`?

Comment: yes they are,same goes with pickup.

Comment: Where are you actually calling `strptime`?  Your posted code assigns the strings directly.

Comment: i defined a function in form class. edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're not actually returning the converted values.

```
delivery_daterange = self.cleaned_data['delivery_daterange']
[...]
return delivery_daterange
```

That just returns the same string, unparsed.  You could do something like this instead:

```
def clean_delivery_daterange(self):
    [...]
    delivery_from = datetime.datetime.strptime(str_delivery_from, "%d %b %Y")
    delivery_to = datetime.datetime.strptime(str_delivery_to, "%d %b %Y")
    return (delivery_from, delivery_to)

def clean_pickup_daterange(self):
    [...]
    pickup_from = datetime.datetime.strptime(str_pickup_from, "%d %b %Y")
    pickp_to = datetime.datetime.strptime(str_pickup_to, "%d %b %Y")
    return (pickup_from, pickup_to)
```

And then in the view:

```
new_obj.date_pickup_from, new_obj.date_pickup_to = form.cleaned_data['pickup_daterange']
```

An alternate approach would be to simply return the text values, then convert to `Date` objects in your view:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    new_obj = form.save(commit=False)
    pickup_start_string, pickup_end_string = form.cleaned_data['pickup_daterange'].split(' to ')
    new_obj.date_pickup_from = strptime(pickup_start_string, "%d %b %Y")
    #...etc
```

A more advanced approach would be to define a [custom field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#form-field-default-cleaning) to cover the concept of a date range, and define its `to_python` method to return, say, a tuple of `Date` objects.

Personally, I would simplify the whole thing and just let `date_pickup_from` and the rest be `DateField` instances in the form, maybe with a custom widget if I wanted to use something like a jQuery DatePicker to help the user pick the dates, and take care of special rendering in the template.

Comment: thanks a lot. any idea on why a custom clean function does not work?
before hand i was using **'delivery_from = datetime.datetime.strptime(str_delivery_from, "%d/%m/%Y")'**

and this was working fine. just when i change the format to ***%d %b %Y***  things went wrong.

Comment: The critical thing is the return value from your `clean` method.  That's what the view will get when you pull the value from `cleaned_data`.

Comment: Oh yeah, and the `clean_delivery_daterange` method is not the right place to check that it comes after the `pickup_daterange`.  For that, you want the form object's `clean` method.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other